# How can I format a code block below a list?

Tags: support, markdown

When I want to list a few things and give a code example below each item how can I do it without writing anything between the list item and the code block?

Example:

- List item

  Code example not formatted as code
- List item

text

```
Code example formatted as code
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Normally, code blocks are formatted using four spaces of indentation:

```
var string = 'string';
```

- In a list, code blocks require eight spaces:

  ```
  var string = 'string';
  ```
- After a list, a code block can be made using four spaces of indentation, but it needs to be after an intervening `<!-- comment -->`.

```
var string = 'string';
```

Comment: A rule of thumb for how many spaces you need is \$4(n + 1)\$ where \$n\$ is the level of nested lists. E.g. no lists is \$4(0 + 1)\$.